# Passar método Post para função

Tags: php

Preciso digitar a variável ID na classe Cliente.php para ela mandar para a classe Servidor.php que vai pesquisar o produto no do Banco de Dados e mostrar novamente no Cliente.php.
**Só que estou tendo dificuldade pra inserir a variável na query** da função que ira fazer a pesquisa no Banco de Dados.

Seguem as classe que já fiz.

Classe Cliente.php

```
<form action="servidor.php" method="post">
Pesquisa: <input type="text" name="pesquisa" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php

include('servidor.php');
$connect = new servidor();
$connect->conectar();
$connect->selecionarDB();

?>
```

Classe Servidor.php

```
$pesquisa = $_REQUEST["pesquisa"];
 `$query = 'SELECT * FROM produtos where id = '.$pesquisa`;
```

**Quero passar essa query para a função executar(), para ela retornar para a Classe Cliente.php**

```
class servidor {

   private $host = localhost; 
   private $bd = banco; 
   private $usuario = root; 
   private $senha = senha; 

   function conectar(){
      $conexao = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->usuario,$this->senha) or die($this->mensagem(mysql_error()));
      return $conexao;
   }


   function selecionarDB(){

      $banco = mysql_select_db($this->bd) or die($this->mensagem(mysql_error()));
      if($banco){
         return true;
      }else{
         return false;
      }
   }

   function executar(){
      $query = mysql_query($this->sql) or die ($this->mensagem(mysql_error()));
      return $query;
   }
```

Comment: De onde vem essa propriedade `sql` da função `executar`? Não está declarada no escopo de propriedades da classe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que percebi, a sua classe não tem um [método mágico](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php) ou um método que define o valor da variável `sql`.

Veja, o seu método `executar` depende dessa variável:

```
//...
$query = mysql_query($this->sql) or die ($this->mensagem(mysql_error()));
```

É preciso definir essa variável na sua classe ou passar para o método `executar` a query que será processada:

```
class servidor 
{
    //...

    function executar($sql){
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ($this->mensagem(mysql_error()));
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Agora basta passar a query como parâmetro:

```
//...

include('servidor.php');
$connect = new servidor();
$connect->conectar();
$connect->selecionarDB();

$pesquisa = $_REQUEST["pesquisa"];
$resultado = $connect->executar("SELECT * FROM produtos where id =  $pesquisa");
```

**Observações:**

O seu sistema está vulnerável a um ataque por [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL), a variável `pesquisa` é injetada na query sem qualquer tratamento facilitando o ataque.

Outro ponto negativo é que embora o sistema utilize classes, isso não quer dizer que seja orientado a objetos, por exemplo, se o projeto passou a utilizar SQLServer no lugar de MySQL, toda a sua classe terá que ser refeita e provavelmente algumas queries deixarão de funcionar e algumas partes da sua aplicação terão mesmo que ser refeitas para suportar o novo banco de dados.

Procure sobre [padrões de projeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software), tenha em mente desde o princípio que isso não é código pronto para situações específicas e sim um modelo para resolver um problema específico.

A base de dados é um serviço externo que é consumido pela sua aplicação, portanto não deveria ser dependente de um banco de dados específico.

No seu caso, utilizar o padrão `Adapter` ajudaria a sua aplicação desacoplar o banco de dados sem que haja a necessidade de alterar a sua implementação, é como um dispositivo adaptador, que permite que um aparelho com determinado padrão de tomada utilize uma fonte que segue outro padrão, ou seja, ao comprar um aparelho com um formato de tomada diferente, você não iria precisar quebrar a sua parede e fazer uma instalação nova só por um aparelho.